# HTML Select with disabled Option returns wrong selectedIndex in FireFox

Tags: html, firefox, drop-down-menu

I have a `Select` with a disabled `Option` wich is the default selected one:

```
<select name="select" size="1">
   <option>0</option>
   <option selected disabled>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
</select>
```

If I get the selected, it returns `1`. Everything OK.

But if I open the popup and hover with the cursor over another `Option` *(for Example '4')* 
and Cancel it via <kbd>ESC</kbd> or by clicking anywhere else.

The `Select` input shows the old value `1` but returns on get selected `4`.

[Example with jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oliholz/aRMpt/)

It doesn't happen with Chrome only FireFox (4/5)

Comment: What is the intent of this? To me at least disabled and selected sound like they should be mutually exclusive and although I can't find anywhere in the spec that explicitly states this I'm not sure why having something selected and disabled makes sense. What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: The user selects something from the box. The admin can enable or disale items from the box. When the user selected and saved some value, aftwerwards the Admin disables this item then the user should see his setting as a disabled selected item. The user opens the box, but does not find any other option he like, so presses ESC. But the next SAVE would change the selected value.

Comment: Ah. I see where you are coming from. To my outside eye it feels like the solution is not to let users continue to have a value that has been explicitly disabled by the admin and either give them a choice of "none applicable" or just force them to choose a new one. I've had a bit of a play though and got no further than Alexander below. Firefox is explicitly firing its change event when you lose focus which implies the browser thinks it has been changed. Perhaps if keeping that option is in fact valid then you don't want "disabled" if it is also "selected". This would seem to solve your problem

Comment: This is a bug in firefox. Notice in other browsers when you move your mouse outside the dropdown the selection box dissapears. While in FireFox it remains. I would submit a bug with firefox so they can work on it so that it will work with disabled items.

Comment: Btw, even though it works, the W3C standard would have you write `selected="selected"` and `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: thanks for the W3C standard, will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the display is not changed when you exit your select this way however firefox is looking for a different selectedValue because it finds the currently selected option as disabled, which in firefox' eyes should be impossible.

The onChange event was not triggered until the onBlur event (which is when the selectedValue would get changed, but this is not what the display is changed to). If we were to reset our value in the onChange event this event might get called again. So by utilising the onBlur event we can provide the following workaround:

`onBlur="javascript:document.getElementsByName('select')[0].selectedIndex = document.getElementsByName('select')[0].selectedIndex;"`

http://jsfiddle.net/aRMpt/22/

I hope I'm making sense here.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I want the original disabled Option on get selectedItem, cause I cancel the selection with `ESC`.

Answer (score 1):

Detect the `esc` key and reset it, here is an example using jQuery (and a dash of your code)

```
$('select').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
  document.getElementsByName('select')[0].selectedIndex = 1;
  }
});
```

**UPDATE** No jQuery Solution

**UPDATE 2** Abstracted out finding event and keycode for re-usability.

**DEMO:** http://wecodesign.com/demos/stackoverflow-6923135.htm

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getEvent( event ) {
    if ( window.event ) return window.event;
    return event;
}
function getKeycode ( event ) {
    if ( event.which ) return event.which;
    else return event.keyCode;
}
changeToDefaultListener = function( event ) {
    theEvent = getEvent( event );
    theKeyCode = getKeycode( theEvent );
    if( theKeyCode == 27 ) {
        document.getElementsByName( 'select' )[0].selectedIndex = 1;
    }
};
</script>
<select name="select" size="1">
   <option>0</option>
   <option selected disabled>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
</select>

<a href="javaScript:alert(document.getElementsByName('select')[0].selectedIndex);">getSelected</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByName('select')[0].onkeyup=changeToDefaultListener;
</script>
```

Comment: @jostster I've updated my example with a non-jQuery solution.

Comment: This unfortunately isn't enough because the bug occurs not just after clicking Escape, but also if you, for example, click into other part of document, if you focus another window and so on.

Comment: @duri This was not the requirement in the scope of the question. "The user opens the box, but does not find any other option he like, so presses ESC"

Comment: @Patrick actually he said by pressing ESC or clicking anywhere else in the document.

Comment: @jobster I banged my head against the wall trying to find a solution, but then realized that clicking anywhere else in the document to cancel a selection in a select is the default behavior of a select. No special code needs to be performed here.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is ugly, but it does exactly what you want (I think).  Basically, I am intercepting all onChange events, and only processing them if there is a corresponding onClick event that results in a changed value.  ALso note that change events are processed before click events.  EDIT: Just relaized this does not work in chrome, so i added some browser detection code so that it only executes in firefox.

NOTE: The current code would not work if the user had tabbed into the select box and made his changes with the error keys, but the method below can be easily adapted to handle that case as well.  You'd simply need to process key events like arrow up or arrow down or TAB or ENTER in the same way clicks are processed below, but only when the select box had focus.

NOTE 2: Playing with this more, the behavior is very strange.  If you escape out of the select, the onChange event is not triggered, but it is saved up.  If at any later time you click *anywhere* on the screen the onChange event will be triggered for the value you were hovering over when you escaped, even though that value was actually changed as soon as you escaped.  So this is getting tricky.  I think you may have to handle the 2 cases separately.  One case to handle click aways, and one to handle escape outs (which patrick answered).

It's getting hairy and I see no elegant way to code this.  How about a note to the user next to the text box saying "Your currently selected option, 1, is no longer available."  Then you could have a select box with only the avalable options.

```
<select name="select" size="1" onChange="handleChange()" onClick="handleClick()" >
  <option>0</option>
  <option selected disabled>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<br />


<script>
var initialValue = document.getElementsByName('select')[0].selectedIndex;
var potentialChange;
var processClick;

function handleClick() {

    //ignore this code if not firefox
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") === -1)
        return;

    var curVal = document.getElementsByName('select')[0].selectedIndex;
    if (!processClick)
        return;
    // a value change click occured, now we actually process it.
    document.getElementsByName('select')[0].value = potentialChange;
}
function handleChange() {
    // save the potential change, which will be used if a real click was detected
    potentialChange = document.getElementsByName('select')[0].selectedIndex;
    processClick = (potentialChange !== initialValue);
    // undo the attempted change, in case of an escape or page click
    // but only on firefox
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")!=-1)
        document.getElementsByName('select')[0].value = initialValue;

    document.getElementsByName('select')[0].value = initialValue;
}
</script>

<a href="javaScript:alert(document.getElementsByName('select')[0].selectedIndex);">getSelected</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The work around I had to use for this is was putting an event listener on the click event of the not selected options in drop down. In the event listener's function I set a global boolean.

```
var selectChanged = false;
$('#select option:not(:selected)').click(function () {
    selectChanged = true;
});
```

Then in the area of the code where I need the selected value of the drop down, I check the boolean:

if the boolean is true I can then use it's new value

if the boolean is false I can get the value from the Html property (which contains the initial value of the dropdown).

```
var selectValue = selectChanged ? $('#select').val() : $($('#select').outerHtml()).find('option:selected').val()
```

This is ugly I know, but this is the only work around I could find.